# How to pass 2 parameters with RCSwitch library?

Tags: programming, rf

I'm learning Arduino's world, but knowing very little about C and C++.

I'm trying to achieve a little RF transmitter which should send the temperature and  humidity from a DHT-11 sensor to a Raspberry Pi.

I'm using the `RCSwitch` library to [send information](https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch/blob/master/examples/SendDemo/SendDemo.ino) with the Arduino, and the `433Utils` library to [receive it](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils/blob/master/RPi_utils/RFSniffer.cpp) on the RPI.

Using those 2 libraries demos, I was able to send an integer, holding temperature or humidity information (`mySwitch.send("00001010");`), and read it on the RPI.

**But how can I send both informations so that the RPI will know which one is the temperature and the humidity ?**

I know I could just send both and assume the lowest is the temperature, but this would be very messy and not very rewarding.

### EDIT :

Following Edgar's answer in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/52992/11604, I know write:

```
void send_string(const char *str){
    int i = 0;
    for (char *p = str; *p; p++ ) {     
        mySwitch.send((i<<8) + *p, 16);
        i++;
    }
}

void loop() {   
    delay(1000); 
    h=40.650;
    t=32.0078;  
    hic=33.586;     
    String x = "$H" + String(h) + "T" + String(t) + "HI" + String(hic); 
    send_string(x.c_str());
}
```

Works perfectly ! (see his complete answer for the RPI-side code)

Comment: `mySwitch.send("T45H50");`, `mySwitch.send("[45;50]");`, `mySwitch.send("T45"); mySwitch.send("H50");`...

Comment: Are you really sending an integer, or are you sending an ASCII representation of the binary bits of an integer?

Comment: The `send()` method take either an integer, a string byte representation or a tri-state code, I cannot send a string directly

Answer (score 1):

The library you have chosen is not designed for transmitting information between nodes. It is intended for sending simple ON/OFF commands to RF-connected switches.  Bending it to send data in the way you want would be difficult.  Not impossible, but difficult.

Instead you should be considering a more suitable system, such as the popular [RadioHead](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) library. It appears to have Raspberry Pi support out of the box:

> Raspberry Pi Uses BCM2835 library for GPIO http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/ Currently works only with RH_NRF24 driver or other drivers that do not require interrupt support. Contributed by Mike Poublon.

Alternatively a small Arduino as an interface between the RF module and the Pi may be another option.

Comment: I think this library is what I was looking for, thanks ! But I don't understand your last sentence, in what is this different than what I'm doing ?

Comment: Actually, RadioHead is far too complicated when you don't fully understand what you are doing (hope I'll get it someday). I found a very good answer with RCSwitch [https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52989/how-to-transmit-string-data-using-the-rc-switch-library](here).